# Get R to treat special characters as literals

Tags: r

I'm writing code to do an ftp upload.  Problem is that the password for the site has a '@' embedded in the password and R seems to think that what follows is the server name.  How can I get R to treat the @ literally.  Note, tried \@ and that has no effect

```
protocol <- "ftp"
server <- "xxxxx.xxx.com"
userpwd <- "xxxxxxx:7gu%S@fo64CEM4sl"

outFilename <- "/content_engagement.csv" 
inFilename <-
```

"//cnd1/database/MatherContentEngagement/APIUploads/content_engagement.csv"

### Upload Data

```
url <- paste0(protocol, "://",userpwd,"@", server, outFilename)
ftpUpload(inFilename,url)
```

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>     Could not resolve host: fo64CEM4sl@xxxxx.xxx.com

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RCurl/versions/1.95-4.11/topics/ftpUpload

Comment: > userpwd <- "xxxxx:7gu%S\\@fo64CEM4sl"
> url <- paste0(protocol, "://",userpwd,"@", server, outFilename)
> ftpUpload(inFilename,url)
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: fo64CEM4sl@xxxx.xxx.com

Comment: Put the login:pass in a separate argument as in the second example at the link above

Comment: IceCreamToucan, yes that worked.  Thank you very much!